# The "Sharing" options inside "Modern SharePoint admin center" are less compared to "Classic sharepoint admin center" for the same site collection

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, sharing, external-sharing

When i access the Sharing settings for a sharepoint site collection inside classic UI, i will get all these options:-
[image]

while if i access the sharing settings for the same site collection inside the modern UI for the SP center admin, i will get these minimal options:-
[image]

now the problem that all the modern site collections will not appear inside the classic sharepoint admin center, so for those sites how i can access all the sharing settings found inside the classic sharing settings? mainly the sharing settings for the "Default link Type" and "default link permissions"?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SharePoint Online PowerShell cmdlets](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell/) to set these values. Using [Set-SPOSite](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/set-sposite), you can use the following:

`Set-SPOSite -DefaultLinkType <value>`

`Set-SPOSite -DefaultLinkPermission <value>`